# Apache .htaccess denying access to important files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm a little confused with the regex & the difference between using `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>`

If you look at the rules below, I've modified them a little and I'm not sure what's right and whats wrong.

```
# Deny access to all important files (Misc)
<FilesMatch "^\.*(error_log|bak|config|ini|log|sh|sql|swp|wp-config\.php|php.ini|\.[hH][tT][aApP].*)$">
order deny,allow
deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access to all .htaccess files (Main)
<FilesMatch "\.htaccess">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access to every type of .htaccess file (Extra check)
<FilesMatch "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][AaPp])$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access to every file EXCEPT the following (High Security)
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "^\.(xml|css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|xlsx|xls|xlsm|doc|docx|pdf)$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

If you look at the first rule, I'm not sure what's correct

```
"^\.*(error_log|bak|config|ini|log|sh|sql|swp|wp-config\.php|php.ini|\.[hH][tT][aApP].*)$"
```

Should I only be looking at the extension?

Does the php.ini and wp-config and .htaccess ones actually even work? Because surely this is looking for: `.wp-config.php` for example which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for just opinion or facing any issue with your existing directives?